# Problems casting an ComObject in VB.net

Tags: vb.net, interop, ms-word

I have a Word.Field object which is a checkbox and the `Type` property equals wdFieldFormCheckBox. I am trying to cast the Word.Field object as Word.CheckBox object but I am getting casting errors.

```
Dim chkBox as Word.CheckBox
chkBox = DirectCast( myFieldInstance, Word.Checkbox)
```

How do I cast a Word.Field object into Word.CheckBox object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible. CheckBox is a property of a FormField object and not a field object.